# Mechanism to retrieve all items from DynamoDB that begin with a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a mechanism to retrieve all items from a Dynamo DB table where the hash key of a GSI begins with a specific string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BEGINS_WITH` condition in your query: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html